# how to print the date collected from datepicker in an editor in MAUI

Tags: .net, datepicker, maui

how can I print the date collected from date picker in an editor or a label in MAUI? I have tried to print the date but it doesn't show anything.

```
                <DatePicker  x:Name="mDatePicker" Style="{StaticResource dateStyle}" MinimumDate="01/01/2020" MaximumDate="12/31/2022" Date="01/01/2022" />

                <Label Style="{StaticResource label1Style}" Text="Location" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />



                <Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Select a Company" Style="{StaticResource comboStyle}">
                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>

                <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="inbtn" Text="In" Style="{StaticResource inButtonStyle}" SemanticProperties.Hint="navigate when clicked" Clicked="OnInClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="outbtn" Text="Out" Style="{StaticResource outButtonStyle}" SemanticProperties.Hint="navigate when clicked" Clicked="OnOutClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't see any code that prints the date. Regardless, use Visual Studio's debugging abilities, to find out what is going on: set a breakpoint in the line of code that prints the date.

Comment: This is the tag<Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={Binding time1},
                              Path=Time,
                              StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0:c}'}" Style="{StaticResource tableContStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  />

Comment: That line of XAML has nothing in it that refers to `picker`. Please add the XAML in that comment to your question, and also show any code or declarations involved in getting from a value in picker, to that XAML. Specifically, show declaration of `time1`, plus the code that sets value of `time1`. Then put breakpoint in your code, so you can stop the app, and see the actual value put into `time1`.

Comment: I see in a comment on one answer that you have tried some different code. Please add that code to the question. (Then anyone who reads this will not have to search through comments to know what you have tried.) Make sure you show ALL changes. If you have XAML `... Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference mDatePicker}, Path=Date ...`, then there must be XAML `x:Name="mDatePicker"` somewhere. Be sure to show that.

Comment: I edited the code... can you please check now

Comment: I see you added `x:Name="mDatePicker"` to the question. Add **all** the code involved in trying to display this value. You must have code (xaml) that **uses** mDatePicker. (I don't want to assume you exactly copied some code from Jessie Zhang's answer; I want you to confirm exactly what you did, by adding it to your question's code.) If it is part of that `Entry Placeholder...` in your comment above, then add that to the question. If you still have `time1` somewhere, then its **declaration** needs to be in the question also. To get good help, show **all xaml/code involved**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set `Reference` to the `DatePicker` and set the `path` to `Date`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
        <DatePicker x:Name="mDatePicker"   MinimumDate="01/01/2020" MaximumDate="12/31/2022" Date="01/01/2022" DateSelected="DatePicker_DateSelected" /> 

        <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference mDatePicker}, Path=Date }"   />
```

If you use `TimePicker`, you can set the `Path` to `Time`

```
    <TimePicker x:Name="timePicker" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference timePicker},
                          Path=Time,
                          StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0:c}'}" />
```

**Update:**

From the new thread you posted, I found that you want to bind the variable `time1`  defined in your `DesktopStartupPage.xaml.cs` to an `Entry`,just as follows:

> ```
>  public DateTime time1 { get; set; }
>
> <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={Binding time1},
>                               Path=Time,
>                               StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0}'}" Style="{StaticResource tableContStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
> ```
>
> />

Then we need to bind the variable directly. And if you want to update the UI once changing the value of the variable, you can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for your page.

Please refer to the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiScrollApp1212.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="10"
            VerticalOptions="Center">


            <DatePicker x:Name="mDatePicker"   MinimumDate="01/01/2020" MaximumDate="12/31/2022" Date="01/01/2022" DateSelected="DatePicker_DateSelected" />

            <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference mDatePicker}, Path=Date, StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0:c}' }"   />


            <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300"  x:Name="inbtn" Text="In"   Clicked="OnInClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" />


            <!--<Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={Binding Time1},  
                              Path=Date,
                              StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0}'}"  />-->

            <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Time1, StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0}'}"  />



        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    //public DateTime time1 { get; set; }

    DateTime _time1;
    public DateTime Time1
    {
        get => _time1;
        set => SetProperty(ref _time1, value);
    }

    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

        Time1 = DateTime.Now;

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }



    private void DatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Time1 = mDatePicker.Date;
    }
    private void OnInClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Time1 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(Time1);

       // GetCachedLocation();
    }



    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: I used your code part. I think it is working. but it doesn't show the date in the entry. do you have an idea?

Comment: <Editor Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={Binding time2},
                              Path=Time,
                              StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0:c}'}" Style="{StaticResource tableContStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference mDatePicker}, Path=Date ,StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0:c}'}" Style="{StaticResource tableContStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />

Comment: Have you added `x:Name` for your `DatePicker`? Above code works on my side.

Comment: I also found that you bind the `Date` for your `Editor `.   The way to use is the same.

Comment: Which platform you are using?

Comment: Hi @DanulHiviVihan, I tested on android emulator. I also tried to test on window, it works just as well.

Comment: need to get clicked time by adding a button and need to print it. how can I do that?

Comment: `need to get clicked time by adding a button and need to print it` Do you want to print the selected date after clicking a button?

Comment: no only the time

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by words `no only the time`. What's the `time` ?

Comment: "No, I need only the time to print."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74782764/16241720 This is the code. Please refer it and give me a solution to print the time that button has been clicked.

Comment: Hi @DanulHiviVihan, I have updated my answer. You can check the updated part at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: In general, we recommend using MVVM for your functionality. And I have posted another answer achieving with MVVM. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we recommend using MVVM for your functionality.

You can add the variable `time1` in the ViewModel of this page. And if you want to update the UI once changing the value of the variable, you can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for your page.

I have achieved this function, you can refer to the following code:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        DateTime _time1;

        // We usually define variable with capital letters as bind's variables. 
        public DateTime Time1  
        {
            get => _time1;
            set => SetProperty(ref _time1, value);
        }

      // add `BtnInCommand` for Button(inbtn)  here   
        public ICommand BtnInCommand => new Command(showDate);

        private void showDate(object obj)
        {

            Time1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
        }

        public MyViewModel() {

            Time1 = DateTime.Now;
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**DesktopStartupPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiScrollApp1212.DesktopStartupPage"
             Title="DesktopStartupPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>


        <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300"  x:Name="inbtn" Text="In"   Command="{Binding BtnInCommand}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

       <!--   bind variable Time1  here-->
        <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Time1, StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0}'}"  />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**DesktopStartupPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class DesktopStartupPage : ContentPage 
{
      public DesktopStartupPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

             // set the BindingContext  for this page    
            this.BindingContext =  new MyViewModel(); 
      }
}
```