# Need to print the clicked time in the entry, when the In button clicked maui

Tags: .net, datetime, binding, maui

I need to print the clicked time on the Entry on the front end. It's not working.
Also, I had an issue on doing this using android emulator, however, the date showing option is the only thing working in Windows.

**Code-behind:**

```
        public partial class DesktopStartupPage: ContentPage{
            public DateTime time1 { get; set; }
    

            public Location location { get; set; }

        public DesktopStartupPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            time1 = DateTime.Now;
        
            location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            BindingContext = this;
         }

        private void OnBackClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
         }

        private void OnInClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time1 = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(time1);
            GetCachedLocation();
         }
        public async Task<string> GetCachedLocation()
        {
           try  {
            if (location != null)
                return $"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}";
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        { }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
        {}
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}return "None";
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
                    <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="inbtn" Text="In" Style="{StaticResource inButtonStyle}" SemanticProperties.Hint="navigate when clicked" Clicked="OnInClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                    <Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="outbtn" Text="Out" Style="{StaticResource outButtonStyle}" SemanticProperties.Hint="navigate when clicked" Clicked="OnOutClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                    <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={Binding time1},
                              Path=Time,
                              StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0}'}" Style="{StaticResource tableContStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Entry Placeholder="text" Text="{Binding Source={Binding time2},
                              Path=Time,
                              StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0:c}'}" Style="{StaticResource tableContStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Comment: If you want the UI to update dynamically when the model changes, you need to use INotifyPropertyChanged or ObservableProperty

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding correctly for `Entry` in xaml. Also, as Jason suggested, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `ObservableProperty`. Here's the sample implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` below for your reference:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class DesktopStartupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private DateTime _time1 = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime time1
        {
            get { return _time1; }
            set
            {
                _time1= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(time1));
            }
        }

        public ICommand myCommand { get; set; }

        public DesktopStartupViewModel()
        {
            myCommand = new Command(SetEntry);
        }

        private void SetEntry(object obj)
        {
            time1 = DateTime.Now;
        }

        


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)

        {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Button HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="300"  x:Name="inbtn" Text="In"  SemanticProperties.Hint="navigate when clicked" Command="{Binding myCommand}" HorizontalOptions="Center" /> 

<Entry  Text="{Binding time1,  StringFormat='The TimeSpan is {0}'}"   />
```

Last but not least, bind the View with ViewModel in code-behind or in Xaml:

```
public DesktopStartupPage() 
{
     InitializeComponent();
     
     BindingContext = new DesktopStartupViewModel(); 
}
```